# Showing the same button many times, depending on Query using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my database I have one table called **Sales**(id_s, username, password)and another Table **Sales_trade**(id_s, trade), the column id_s is a primary key in table Sales and it's a foreign key in table Sales_trade, here is a capture of the Sales_trade table:

[image]

Now what I need is an idea or a sample to do this work:

for every id_s , show the button, the number of times of the trade , and the name of these trades should be writing on the buttons that have been shown.

The query should look something like: select **trade** where id_s=4

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in an asp.net page you can add a SQLDatasource that performs the query you want, and put the button in a Repeater Control, binding the control to the SQLDataSource.
You can find examples of that on MSDN.